# What is the difference between gtag implementation and gtm implementations?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new with the new API of google analytics, so I noticed now we also have GTM and as far as I understand is now we can use it to configure events and some other things using GTM tool directly without write any line of code.

GTM is something we don't need for the moment, so I decided to use the gtag.js core to create my implementation.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

And using that script I access the dataLayer array with `gtag({object})` So first I tried with this:

```
gtag({'event' : 'MyCustomEvent',
'eventCategory' : 'MyCustomCategory',
'eventValue': undefined})
```

But events were not triggered until I modified my code to:

```
gtag('event' : 'MyCustomEvent', {
'event_category' : 'MyCustomCategory',
'event_value': undefined})
```

Are gtm and gtag different in the core? I mean, do each dataLayer works different in each implementation? I ask this because the first implementation should work as far as I understood.

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-tag-manager-custom-event-trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Both **Tag Manager** and **gtag.js** perform similar functions:

- Tag Manager is a tag management system that allows you to quickly and easily update tags on your website or mobile app from a web interface.
- gtag.js is the JavaScript framework that is used to add Google tags directly to web pages.

Both solutions are built on the same core Google infrastructure, and are interoperable. You are free to choose the solution that best suits your needs.

Consider **Tag Manager** if you need:

- The ability to deploy and modify both Google and 3rd party tags
- The ability to deploy and modify tags for both web and mobile apps
- The ability to deploy and modify tags on the fly from a web interface
- Collaboration and versioning capabilities

Consider **gtag.js** if you are unable to use Google Tag Manager, or the following capabilities are important to you:

- The ability to install tags directly on your web page, without the ramp-up time of setting up a tag management system
- The ability to work with your tags directly in JavaScript without being required to work with a separate interface

https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7582054?hl=en